# Generating a Crystal Reports Report in Java and Passing an ID as a Parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, crystal-reports

I am working on a Java project where I need to generate a report using Crystal Reports and then export it to a PDF file. My goal is to achieve this within a specific Java function, to which an ID will be passed as a parameter. However, I am facing difficulties in understanding how I can effectively achieve this integration.

My question revolves around how I can structure this process in an organized manner. Here is the flow I have in mind:

Receive an ID as a parameter in a Java function.

I want to call a pre-designed report in Crystal Reports from this function.

Pass the ID collected in step 1 as a parameter to the Crystal Reports report.

Generate the report in Crystal Reports using the provided ID.

Export the generated report to a PDF file.

I am seeking guidance on how I can achieve each of these steps effectively. I would like to know how I can establish communication between Java and Crystal Reports, how to pass the ID as a parameter to the report, and how to finally generate and export the report in PDF format.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide me with clear examples, code snippets, or useful resources that help me understand and resolve this issue. I am confident that this community has experience in integrating Java and Crystal Reports, and any assistance you can provide will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance on this matter!

In my pursuit of a viable solution, I have diligently experimented with multiple libraries, including JasperReports, in an effort to establish a functional integration between Java and Crystal Reports. However, despite my endeavors, I have encountered roadblocks that have thus far hindered my progress

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.